# text processing using awk or sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I tried with the code using awk and sed utility as below to parse the matching pattern only inside the quotes, but it takes the whole line.

Code:

```
awk '/''/ { print }' parse.xml
```

input

```
<msg time='005-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='lsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='localhost'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1' pid='6322'>
 <txt>05:34:54 * service_update * orclcdb * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

Expect output

```
Time      Org_id  Comp_id Type     Level Host_id   Host_addr  Pid  Txt
-----     ------- ------- -----    ----- -------   ---------  ---- --- 
005-04:00 oracle  lsnr    UNKNOWN  16    localhost 127.0.0.1  6322 05:34:54 * service_update * orclcdb * 0
```

Comment: I think it would be a much better idea to parse xml using an xml parser. As for getting out things between single quotes, with awk you can split by the single quote and print out every other column: `awk -F"'" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i=i+2){print $i}}'` this gets uglier if your quotes strings span multiple lines, or if you need to also preserve the `<msg>` tag they are contained within as a single row, and also as you need to grab the innertext of the `<txt>` tag... each little bit you add is going to make it uglier and uglier until you use an xml parser to gain your sanity back.

Comment: Your question title of `text processing using awk or sed` is bad as it tells us, and anyone with a similar question searching the archives in future for a solution, nothing about your actual question. Please fix that.

Comment: How do you think the shell will parse `awk '/''/ { print }' parse.xml` and why do you think it is any different than `awk '// { print }' parse.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

Making multiple assumptions about what might be inside your quoted strings, for the input you show we can do the following With GNU awk for multi-char RS, FPAT, gensub(), and \s/\S shorthand:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = "</msg>"
    OFS = "\t"
    FPAT = "[[:alnum:]_]+=|'[^']*'|<txt>.*</txt>"
}
{ $0 = gensub(/<(txt)>(.*\S)\s*<\/txt>/,"\\1='\\2'",1) }
FNR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        $i = toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
        sub(/=/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1) ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
        gsub(/./,"-",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1) ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        gsub(/^'|'$/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
Time       Org_id  Comp_id  Type     Level  Host_id    Host_addr  Pid   Txt
----       ------  -------  ----     -----  -------    ---------  ---   ---
005-04:00  oracle  lsnr     UNKNOWN  16     localhost  127.0.0.1  6322  05:34:54 * service_update * orclcdb * 0
```

Comment: There is no file input also the print option is for 6 fields but the required fields are 9.

Comment: Your example `awk '/''/ { print }' parse.xml` specifically shows file input but anyway, file input or pipe input or stdin input - just run the script on a file, pipe, or stdin just like you would any other tool. I don't know what `the print option is for 6 fields but the required fields are 9` means.

Comment: @DevopsDevelop did this solve your problem or not? If not - it produces exactly the output you asked for from the sample input you provided so in what way is it not doing exactly what you wanted? If the example in your question is wrong or you have additional/different requirements then please update your question to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment. I think it's a bad idea to parse XML using sed or awk, although it's done. Better though is python with it's built in xml library. Something like the following would do the trick:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# load xml from file
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#open a text file and write out the header
with open("test.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['time', 'org_id', 'comp_id', 'type', 'level', 'host_id', 'host_addr', 'pid', 'txt'])
    writer.writeheader()
    
    #loop through every msg at root
    for msg in root.findall('.'):    
        #dump the msg tag's attributes to a dictionary named "row"    
        row=msg.attrib
        #add to the dict for the <txt> tag's text
        row['txt']= msg[0].text
        #write it out
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Going this route your code is much more easily modified should you encounter any changes or complexity to your incoming XML like if there is more than one `msg` tag that should be written as it's own row, or if there is more than one `<txt>` tag in a message, or should your attribute texts span more than one line.

Comment: FWIW GNU awk also has an XML library, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawkextlib.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ruby` as a lightweight XML parser to do this:

```
ruby -r nokogiri -e '
BEGIN{h={};a=[]}
doc=Nokogiri::XML($<.read)
doc.xpath("//msg/@* | //msg/*").each{ |e| 
    h[e.name]=e.value rescue h[e.name]=e.text.rstrip()}
h.map{|k,v| 
    w=[k.length, v.length].max; a.append([k.center(w," "),"-"*w,v.center(w," ")])}
[0,1,2].each{|i| a.each{|e| printf("%s ", e[i])}; puts}
' file
```

Prints:

```
  time    org_id comp_id  type   level  host_id  host_addr pid                    txt                   
--------- ------ ------- ------- ----- --------- --------- ---- --------------------------------------- 
005-04:00 oracle  lsnr   UNKNOWN  16   localhost 127.0.0.1 6322 05:34:54 * service_update * orclcdb * 0
```

You can also use `xmlstarlet` to process the XML:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//msg/@* | //msg/*" -v "concat(name(),'=',.)" -n file
time=005-04:00
org_id=oracle
comp_id=lsnr
type=UNKNOWN
level=16
host_id=localhost
host_addr=127.0.0.1
pid=6322
txt=05:34:54 * service_update * orclcdb * 0
```

Then use `awk` to format that:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//msg/@* | //msg/*" -v "concat(name(),'=',.)" -n file |
awk  '{arr[++n]=$0}
END{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    split(arr[i], parts, "=")
    w=(length(parts[1])>length(parts[2]) ? length(parts[1]) : length(parts[2]))
    l1=l1 (sprintf("%-*s", w, parts[1]) " ")
    l2=l2 (gensub(/ /, "-", "g", sprintf("%*s", w, "")) " ")
    l3=l3 (sprintf("%-*s", w, parts[2]) " ")
    }
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",l1,l2,l3)
}'
```

Prints:

```
time      org_id comp_id type    level host_id   host_addr pid  txt                                      
--------- ------ ------- ------- ----- --------- --------- ---- ---------------------------------------  
005-04:00 oracle lsnr    UNKNOWN 16    localhost 127.0.0.1 6322 05:34:54 * service_update * orclcdb * 0
```